# Is this AddMonths(number) a valid way of adding month in C#?

Tags: c#

I know you can add months using `AddMonths(number)`, but I was debugging code that doesn't assign the `AddMonths(number)` to a `DateTime` variable directly.

```cs
var dat = new DateTime(2015, 12, 31);

//I am sure this will add 6 months
dat = dat.AddMonths(6);

//I am not sure what this code does
dat.AddMonths(6);
```

Is the last sentence incorrect? I think it does nothing, but I am not sure.

If so, I want to understand why it does nothing and why is not marked as incorrect code in Visual Studio.

[In .NET fiddle, it does nothing](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YFskM4).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check the [definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.addmonths?view=netcore-3.1) of the AddMonths methods, you will find the following:

> public DateTime AddMonths (int months);

which means that the method is returning a new DateTime with added months.
The second call is just calling the AddMonths on the returned DateTime and you don't use the new returned value that's why it seems like nothing happened, so there is nothing invalid.

Try to run the below code, I think it will make everything more clear

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var dat = new DateTime(2015, 12, 31);
        //I am sure this will add 6 months
        dat = dat.AddMonths(6);
        Console.WriteLine(dat);
        Console.WriteLine(dat.AddMonths(6));    
        Console.WriteLine(dat); 
    }
}
```

As a conclusion I will add that it doesn't make sense to call the `DateTime.AddMonths(x)` method without working with the returned value as it is not changing the `DateTime` that you are passing to it.

Comment: Good point. A compiler can tell you what is invalid, not necessarily what is useless.

Answer (score 0):

There are two line of code in the question: one with an assignment and one without. This line:

```
dat.AddMonths(6);
```

with no assignment, still creates a brand new `DateTime` value for six months after the existing `dat` value, just like the other line with the assignment. But then it throws the new `DateTime` value away. The value is returned from the method, but there's nothing waiting to receive it.